# cannot assign string to tabitem.name

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

Im sure this is really simple and an almost stupid question, but i cant seem to figure out why the following code is not working when tab.name is expecting a string assigned to it.

I am trying to assign a `guid.tostring()` to a tabitem.name

```
TabItem tab = new TabItem();
tab.Name = id.ToString(); //id is a guid
```

I just get the following error

> "1db465a3-b8f2-4cb9-a72d-1bc83c3861ab" ist kein gültiger Wert für die
>   Eigenschaft "Name".

Comment: Can you please translate your error message to English?

Comment: Perhaps you can make use of `Tag` instead of `Name`?

Answer (score 1):

From the [FrameworkElement.Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name.aspx) page on MSDN:

> The string values used for Name have some restrictions, as imposed by
>   the underlying x:Name Directive defined by the XAML specification.
>   Most notably, a Name must start with a letter or the underscore
>   character (_), and must contain only letters, digits, or underscores.
>   For more information, see WPF XAML Namescopes.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name(v=vs.110).aspx) the Name property must start with a letter or underscore character and must contain only letters, digits, or underscores.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using WPF, which is looks like you are, there are actually some restrictions put in place for naming within WPF, one of them being that names cannot start with a number.